# Plugin.FilePicker CrossFilePicker not picking files from SD card. (Xamarin Forms Android Only)

Tags: xamarin.forms, filepicker

When i try to pick file from SD card, CrossFilePicker throws exception "System.IO.DirectoryNotFound Exception".

```
file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
        if (file == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        fileData = file.DataArray;
        filePath = file.FilePath;
```

Do i need to add anything specific to access file from SD card.

Note: I added ReadExternalStorage, WriteExternalStorage permissions.

Thanks,
Santhosh

Comment: Which one are you using? What version? What have you tried? I'm sorry but there is too little info to be able to help you. Also you would probably be better off opening an issue at the repository this plugin belongs to. Also, for future reference, please check the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Comment: Am using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.FilePicker/             version : 1.3.0.0 Xamarin Forms version 2.0.0.0

Comment: Please try nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker/ beta packages

Comment: Getting the same error with this packages